# Apoc procedure - Trigger ID and increment

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

which is the correct APoc procedure to Trigger an ID and Increment it +1 every time I call a create?

Assuming User has an ID - my idea is to increment using ID and not UUID.

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('create-event-gen-id',"UNWIND {createdNodes} AS e
MATCH (n:User) 
set e.ID=e.ID + 1", {phase:'after'});
```

Do you think this one is correct?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was how I solved My trigger.

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('triggeredID',
"UNWIND $createdNodes AS e MATCH(n:User)  
with e, MAX(n.ID) as maxId 
 Set e.ID = maxId + 1", {phase:'before'})
```

please note that you have to make a Match after in order to get back the ID.